# How can one connect Microsoft Flow directly to Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, power-automate

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL database and retrieve the manager's email of every user that submits a response in Microsoft form. The flow is as below:

> Microsoft Form(user fills in personal details) --> When response is
>   submitted I need to retrieve the user's manager's email from Azure SQL DB
>   to sent approval email --> When Approval is received, I need to store
>   the details in Azure DB again but in different table.

Is there a way to connect Microsoft Forms to Azure SQL DB and how do I retrieve the manager's email address?